# Output file not written in specific path using "~"

Tags: c++

I have already searched threads for storing file in specific location but my problem persists.

I am trying to write file to a specific path and I could not find the file. However, if I ask the program to write the file to the current directory, it works.
In both ways, I do not get any error. My sample code is below.

```
string path="~\Documents\trialrun\"; file_name="abc.dat";
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(""+path+""+file_name+"",fstream::append);
```

This does not write the file at all, whereas

```
 outfile.open(""+file_name+"",fstream::append);
```

Comment: `+""+` - why is this everywhere? I don't get how `"~\Documents\trialrun\"; file_name="abc.dat"` compiles. Learn how to [escape characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: Please, make your code example syntactically correct. As it is now it contains multiple problems and won't compile.

Comment: Double up those backslashes: `path="~\\Documents\\trialrun\\"`

Answer (score 3):

*For the purposes of this answer, I will assume that the broken backslash in your code's first line is not in your real code.*

`~\Documents\trialrun` is not a valid path. That tilde is a shorthand that will be expanded by a shell environment like Bash, but you're not using Bash! You're declaring an actual path.

You will have to use platform-specific APIs to expand the path into its "real" equivalent as Bash would do, or write out the path in full to begin with.

Comment: I too had the same thought but while reading the infile, the path specified (~\Documents\trialrun\infile.dat) is correctly taken by the script. Any inputs on this?

Comment: @vidhya: What infile? What path? What script? And so what?

Comment: I read a file using the script ifstream infile; infile.open(""+path+""+file_name1+"");

Comment: @vidhya: I think it's time you showed us an actual MCVE (without buggy backslashes, for example). And name your platform. And versions for everything. Give us _specifics_. Actually, you should have done that from the start.

Comment: Yeah ok, I will implement that from now. Thanks for the input. :)